# 301 redirect loops within the same domain to different server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, shopify

I'm not sure how to properly articulate this question, so thanks for your patience.

I'm migrating a website to a new server (Shopify).  I have too many inbound links to use their built-in 301 solution because they don't support wildcard redirects.  Setting up a secondary server to handle the redirects would work, but since the old domain and the new one are the same how do I prevent redirect loops?

For example:

```
old url: mystore.com?p=123&q=456&r=789
new url: mystore.com/products/some-meaningful-string
```

My redirect server:

```
[code to create the new url from mystore.com?p=123&q=456&r=789]
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: mystore.com/products/some-meaningful-string");
```

Is there a way to set up the dns so that the registrar thinks the domain is on the redirect server, and the redirect server points to Shopify? I am wondering if the technique CDNs use would help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sucks that you cannot generate a simple sitemap of all your current (soon to be old) URLs. That is really your only sane choice, without deep diving into the crazy.

A simple loop and with one line of code, you generate a 301 redirect and Shopify kicks in appropriately and you lose no juice on the old URLs.

Are you sure you cannot just write a simple script to tease out a listing of all your old URLs and map them to new ones?

Comment: I have that list. Unfortunately the old urls were constructed to track navigation so there are too many inbound links for Shopify to handle, and a site map would lose all my search authority.  Looks like I'm stuck in deep crazy.  :(

Comment: Oh well.. you can at least curse the person(s) that left you with such a useless mess to clean up. Or just skip it altogether. Why useless internal nav links are of any value to you anyway is your battle now, not so much technology